# Does Flash save automated backups?

Tags: flash, backup

Does Adobe Flash save the project automatically in a backup file somewhere?  Or do I have to do the entire thing again (not the whole project but what got lost 2+hours)?

If I'm right, even Word creates backups over time.

If flash creates backups, I shouldn't overwrite it by opening the file again and remaking what I did. If it doesn't, I should.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. You may want to backup your projects manually from now on. You may upload them on some online storage device as GoogleDrive or simply copy them on some other physical location.